# nomethoderror for rack::utils::escape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails so I apologize for my ignorance.

I'm setting a constant in a class outside of a method:

```
PARAM = { #... => ...
          'field' => escape('somethingwith/slashes')
}
```

and get a NoMethodError: undefined method 'escape'

I tried Rack::Utils::escape and Rack::Utils.escape instead, but both don't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CGI.escape.

```
# lib/my_foo
class MyFoo
  THINGS = {
    :hi => CGI.escape("well hello, there.")
  }
end
```

If yo do this outside of the Rails environment, you'll have to `require "cgi"` as well.

Comment: gives me the same error. undefined method 'escape' for #<UsersController:0x4d403c4>

any thoughts?

Comment: you need to require "CGI" so that you can use the escape method.

Comment: That is because you should use `CGI.escape`, not `escape`. Look closely at the snippet ;)

Comment: The same error appears if I "require 'CGI'" or "require 'cgi'"

Comment: `CGI.escape` works for me. The error you pasted above tells me that `escape` was called on an instance of UsersController, not on `CGI`. Double check your code

Answer (score 2):

What version of Rails are you using. If you're using Rails 2.3, you should have Rack available. Check this out:

```
>> require "rack" # Rails 2.3 and above has already done this
=> true
>> Rack::Utils.escape("the quick brown fox")
=> "the+quick+brown+fox"
```

If you're using a version of Rails older than 2.3, you'll need to install and require Rack yourself.

```
sudo gem install rack
```

Or, if you're managing gems from inside Rails, add the following line to your environment.rb inside the Initializer block:

```
config.gem "rack", "1.0.0"
```

Once you upgrade to Rails 2.3 or higher, you'll be able to use the version of Rack built-in with Rails, and you can remove the config.gem line.